# In how many ways can the ball come back to $A$ after seven passes?

Tags: combinatorics

There are 4 basketball players $A,B,C,D$.Initially the ball is with $A$.The ball is always passed from one person to a different person.In how many ways can the ball come back to $A$ after seven passes?

I could somehow get the solution as $2.3^5=486$ passes but I am not sure
about my answer.An answer with full explanation would be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: An equivalent question is how many sequences of $8$ letters, containing A, B, C or D with no consecutive identical letters, that start with A and end with A are there.

Comment: @barak: 7 passes corresponds to 8 letters, I think.

Comment: @TonyK: Yep, corrected. Thanks :)

Comment: @TonyK: But I think that the answer to is in fact $3^6$...

Comment: @barak manos Sir I thought that way but I have no idea of solving such questions because I am quite unfamiliar with combinatorics.

Comment: @barak: I don't think the calculation is so simple. For instance, the ball can't be at $A$ after 6 passes.

Comment: @TonyK: So it's B or C or D for letters #2 and #7. It's still $3$ options per letter, right?

Comment: @barakmanos: Suppose you have done it that way and end up with $B?A$ in the end. How many possibilities do we have for $?$ here?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Just for your interest,The formula given by TonyK and robjohn also satisfies the recursion $f(n)+f(n-1)=3^{n-1}$ is it possible to arrive at this recursion directly?Handling this recursion is indeed easier.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A(n)$ be the number of ways to end at $A$ after $n$ passes.  Let $B(n)$ be the number of ways to end at $B$ after $n$ passes.  Clearly $C(n)=B(n)=D(n)$.
$A(1)=0,B(1)=1$
$A(n+1)=3B(n)$
$B(n+1)=2B(n)+A(n)$
It is now simple to calculate $A(7)$.
When $A$ receives the $n+1^{th}$ pass, the previous player was $B,C or D$ after $n$ passes, so $A(n+1)=B(n)+C(n)+D(n).$
When $B$ receives the $n+1^{th}$ pass, either $A,C or D$ received the nth pass, so $B(n+1)=A(n)+C(n)+D(n)$.
Since $B(n)=C(n)=D(n)$, that means $A(n+1)=3B(n)$.
To calculate $A(7)$, first calculate $A(2)$ and $B(2)$, then $A(3)$ and $B(3)$, and so on.

Comment: I am sorry sir but I didn't get you at all.How is $A(n+1)=3B(n)$ and $B(n+1=2B(n)+A(n)$ and even if it is so how do we calculate $A(7)$ from it?

Comment: When $A$ receives the $n+1$th pass, the previous player was $B,C$ or $D$ after $n$ passes, so $A(n+1)=B(n)+C(n)+D(n)$.  When $B$ receives the $n+1$th pass, either $A,C$ or $D$ received the $n$th pass, so $B(n+1)=A(n)+C(n)+D(n)$.  Since $B(n)=C(n)=D(n)$, that means $A(n+1)=3B(n)$.  To calculate $A(7)$, first calculate $A(2)$ and $B(2)$, then $A(3)$ and $B(3)$, and so on.

Comment: @Michael: perhaps you should include your comment in your answer to clarify what is going on.

Comment: @Michael Sir did you also note that $B(n)=A(n-1)$ for all even $n$s and $B(n)=A(n+1)$ for all odd $n$s!This makes the calculations even easier.

Answer (score 5):

For each number of passes $n$, let $u_n$ be the number of pass sequences ending at $A$ and $v_n$ be the number of pass sequences not ending at $A$. Then we have:

$$u_{n+1} = v_n$$
$$v_{n+1} = 3u_n + 2v_n$$

Substituting $u_n = v_{n-1}$ in the second equation gives

$$v_{n+1} = 3v_{n-1} + 2v_n$$

This is a standard linear recurrence (see for instance [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#General_methods)). The polynomial $x^2-2x-3$ has roots $3$ and $-1$, so $v_n=A\cdot3^n+B\cdot(-1)^n$ for some constants $A$ and $B$. Using the initial values $v_0=0$ and $v_1=3$, we get $A+B=0$ and $3A-B=3$, which gives $A=\frac34, B=-\frac34$.

Hence $v_n = \frac34(3^n-(-1)^n)$, and $u_n$ (which is what we want here) is equal to $v_{n-1} = \frac34(3^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}) =\frac143^n + \frac34(-1)^n$.

The final answer is therefore $u_7 = \frac14(3^7-3) = 546$.

Comment: (+1) You answered first, but I do think there should be more explanation of the recursion, so I will leave my answer unless you object.

Comment: @robjohn: Your answer is certainly different, and of course I have no objections. You may have explained the recursion more fully, but you don't explain how to solve it! So the best answer is a combination of the two.

Comment: Ah, I misread your argument the first time and thought it was the same, but indeed it is different, and can perhaps do without more explanation.

Comment: @TonyK  i know you have posted this years ago but i have marked an interesting thing in the resulting formula.the final formula also satisfies the recursion $$f(n)+f(n-1)=3^{n-1}$$ is it possible to arrive at this recursion directly?It would perhaps make calculations easier.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let the number of circuits that get back to $A$ after $n$ passes be $f(n)$

We have two cases. Either pass $n-2$ is to $A$ or it is not.

If pass $n-2$ is to $A$, then the pass $n-1$ can be to any other player. Thus, the number of such circuits is $3f(n-2)$.

If pass $n-2$ is not to $A$, then pass $n-1$ is to one of the two people other than $A$ and the person who got pass $n-2$. Thus, we can substitute $A$ for the receiver of pass $n-1$, and get a unique $n-1$ circuit. Thus, the number of such circuits is $2f(n-1)$.

Therefore, we get the recursion
$$
f(n)=2f(n-1)+3f(n-2)
$$
with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. This [linear recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) has the solution
$$
f(n)=\frac{3^n+3(-1)^n}4
$$

Comment: i know you have posted this years ago but i have marked an interesting thing in the resulting formula.the final formula also satisfies the recursion $$f(n)+f(n-1)=3^{n-1}$$ is it possible to arrive at this recursion directly?It would perhaps make calculations easier.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A_ _ _ _ _ _ A : we have to find out in how many ways we can fill the 6 dashes with players B,C,D,A .

**Case 1**: when A does not gets ball in between. then A can pass the ball in 3 ways (B,C,D) , then B,C OR D can pass the ball in 2 ways and so on...
so we have : 3*2*2*2*2*2 ways in which A gets ball.

**Case 2:** When A gets ball once in between either in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th pass.

then we have 4*(3*3*2*2*2) ways of arranging the players.

**Case 3:** When A gets ball twice in between ( twice is the maximum times it can get the ball in between):
the two times A gets the pass can be 2nd and 5th, 2nd and 4th, 3rd and 5th.

so there are 3*(3*3*2*2) ways.

Total: 162+ 96+288=546 
:)